# Is it possible to make the mouse in Windows click on the down press without the release?

Tags: windows, mouse

My son is disabled. He plays this PC game called Tibia, just a simple point and click game.

I noticed when he played he would have to click 2 or 3 times before his character would move. This was because his hand spasms and moves before the release of the down press. So what I'm looking for is a way to skip straight to the click without waiting for the mouse release.

Comment: Sadly this is going to be highly dependent on the game or application. Most actions on the computer do indeed happen on the down press, otherwise we would not be able to click and drag to select text. It might be possible to write an AutoHotkey script that upon left clicking (mouse click down) would wait a brief period would force a mouse click up. The problem is that it would then effectively disable any desirable click and drag. Maybe it would need another key like 'Alt' to disable the unclick event in that case...

Comment: May I respectfully suggest using Google to search for "mouse for disabled people with hand spasms".  Kensington offer numerous such mice (depending on the particular need.  I also saw the name AirO2bic for people with hand issues. Likely an ordinary mouse is not going to work for you.

Comment: It can indeed be done with AutoHotKey(AHK), with the above mentioned problem. You could also use AHK to simulate a left click with a key on the keyboard.

Comment: Tibia can be played with keyboard most of the time because you can bind a lot of actions to hotkeys, is this something to consider for your son? Of course some actions would still require the mouse.

Comment: Be aware that changing this behavior may have unintended side effects with other software.

Comment: Some of these comments look suspiciously like answers...

Comment: Sidenote, since some people have suggested AutoHotKey. It looks like [it is allowed in Tibia](https://tibia.fandom.com/wiki/Hotkeys#:~:text=In%20Tibia%2C%20players%20can%20set,use%20some%20other%20client%20feature.) but [this is not the case for every game](https://secure.runescape.com/m=news/mouse-keys---changes--clarification?oldschool=1). So be careful in implementing the solution, if you decide to use such softwares make sure it's OK with the game you will use them in.

Comment: @AlexandreAubrey I see you posted this comment 20 minutes ago. Nevertheless, the "[this is not the case for every game](https://secure.runescape.com/m=news/mouse-keys---changes--clarification?oldschool=1)" link gives me a 404

Comment: @AlexandreAubrey the link works fine.

Answer (score 46):

Here is an [AutoIt script](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/). First [install AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/cgi-bin/getfile.pl?autoit3/autoit-v3-setup.exe). Then create an file with the extension `.au3` (so like `test.au3`) and put the following text in there:

```
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>

HotKeySet("{ESC}","Quit")

While 1
    Sleep(1)
    If _IsPressed('01') Then
        MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT)
    EndIf
WEnd

Func _IsPressed($HexKey)
   Local $AR
   $HexKey = '0x' & $HexKey
   $AR = DllCall("user32","int","GetAsyncKeyState","int",$HexKey)
   If NOT @Error And BitAND($AR[0],0x8000) = 0x8000 Then Return 1
   Return 0
EndFunc

Func Quit()
    Exit
EndFunc
```

You can doubleclick on the script to start it.

As soon as you press the mouse button down it immediately clicks. If you press <kbd>Escape</kbd> the script stops.

I have made it into a little program. You can download it here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZcAO8apIbl0SY4vYZPUzW8htYjnIyIe3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @GarryFisher I'll bookmark this post, if you need any modifications to the script post a comment here.

Comment: Perhaps he needs the Escape button to go to the menu of the game. You can change ESC in the script above to any of the keys you see on the left hand side in the table (if you scroll down a bit) on this page https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm

Comment: `While 1` will spin up the computer fans. Does AutoIt have no better way to detect a click?

Comment: @user253751 It won't cause the DLL call isn't that fast. Detecting clicks is not what OP asked for.

Comment: Hopefully OP comes back to accept this, unless you guys opted to get rid of the accepted answers all together. ++1

Comment: @Gantendo that just means the computer is spending all its time making DLL calls.

Comment: While this seems like a good answer, this won't work for OP because Tibia includes an anti-cheat system that blocks programs like AutoHotkey and AutoIt.

Comment: @Nohus Have you tried it? Do you have any evidence for that claim? Googling "Tibia autohotkey" I found quite a few scripts.

Comment: @Gantendo Many of these scripts you can find on Google were created before the anti-cheat system (BattlEye) was added. The game also has a big community of private servers, which don't have the anti-cheat system and so the scripts work there.
The inner workings of BattlEye are not known to me, but almost all uses of AutoHotkey in Tibia would be for cheating purposes and players are definitely banned for it. I can only refer to the official rules: https://www.tibia.com/support/?subtopic=tibiarules&rule=3b

Of course this case is not for cheating, but an anti-cheat program can't know that.

Comment: I may have used the wrong word with "blocked", my point is that while it may work, OP should be careful since this can get his account banned for using unofficial software to interact with the game client, which is against the game rules.

Answer (score 45):

The free and open source AutoHotKey (AHK) can do this very easily:

```
#IfWinActive, Tibia
LButton:: 
  Click
  return
LButton UP::
  ; do nothing, avoid spurious "up" events
  return
```

The `#IfWinActive` makes sure that the behaviour triggers only within that game. If the string "Tibia" is not in the actual window title of the game, you can use a spy application shipping with AutoHotKey to find a correct selector. This solution is purely event based, so has no performance overhead and does not lag behind if the PC is busy.

This can be arbitrarily extended. For example you can change it so that if you press another key, the behaviour is temporarily disabled, you could opt to act the 4th or 5th mouse button as a click-and-release left button, and so on. Have a gander through the [AutoHotKey Usage and Syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Program.htm) chapter to see what's possible.

AHK can provide plenty of "quality of life" features, only limited by your imagination. For example it can scan the screen for specific images/icons, and perform actions if it detects certain things, and so on. I'd highly recommend for someone who is limited in what they can do with mouse or keyboard to have a deep look into it.

Answer (score 18):

Gantendo has generously provided an excellent solution.

If, for whatever reason, that solution doesn't work for you and your son, or you desire a tool with additional features and flexibility, I can highly recommend [X-Mouse Button Control (XMBC)](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) by Phillip Gibbons.

XMBC is a feature-rich gratis (donations accepted by the author) software tool for Windows that allows you to define functions of all pointing device buttons as well as combinations of buttons.  It handles events such as "button up" and "button down" very well.  It is extraordinarily powerful and flexible.

Comment: I stumbled upon this question on my search for a solution for [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/91074/thinkpad-trackpoint-scrolling-and-middle-click-possible) that still works on current windows versions and synaptics drivers. Tried XMBC and found that it works like a charm for that -- thanks for that hint, it solved a different problem for me!

Comment: @orithena Great to hear it helped you with a different issue as well!  It's truly a great program, and the developer is a nice person.  It's one of the few reasons I haven't completely switched to Linux.  I haven't found anything quite like it for Linux.

Answer (score 8):

Can your son use a trackball instead of a mouse? This lets him lift his fingers off the ball before clicking on the buttons.

A touchpad is another solution, again he can lift his fingers before clicking. However most touchpads have tap-to-click which is likely to be very frustrating. Make sure that the pad allows this feature to be turned off before buying one.

Or he might prefer using his feet to trigger the mouse buttons. These appear to the computer as second mouse, but it only sends button clicks. Some can be configured to send ctrl/shift/alt with the click.
A list of them is available here, amongst other places

https://www.healthyworkstations.com/productbygroup.asp?PrGrp=1158

I found this by doing a web-search for 'mouse button pedals'

Windows allows several mice and keyboards to be connected (and used at the same time - they act as one), so the family can continue to use the standard mouse if they prefer it.

Comment: I was going to write my own answer until I saw this. I have been a **huge** trackball fan for many, many years (probably goes back to my [Missile Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missile_Command) days). Trackballs solve the "click without moving" problem and are much better for the wrist and don't require as much desk space.

Comment: Aliexpress has a bunch of cheaper foot pedals I've been looking at - they might be an alternate source to kinesis if you're looking at seeing *if* it'll work https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20211118023548&SearchText=foot+pedal+usb+mouse should leave out the sewing machine foot pedals

Comment: @JourneymanGeek that prompts ancient memories of a second, spare mouse (castrated non-optical) with a pad taped to the left button, on the floor  under the desk

Answer (score 4):

There have been some great free solutions presented here.
On the costly side, you could buy him a "gamer" mouse, a lot of them come with software that allows to remap buttons on your mouse. You can easily create macros and assign them to whichever click/button on the mouse.
The brand Razer and its software razer synapse allows you to do such things, I've had a very similar usecase where I remapped keys on the keyboard to execute "key release" on "key press", and to top it all off, you can assign mouse/keyboard profiles to certain applications so that this particular behavior only happens when using that specific application.

Answer (score 0):

There's various software and hardware to address some of the issues disabled people have with using computers. This isn't an exhaustive list, by any means, but they seem to address your specific issue (or similar) with needing longer mouse presses to represent a click.

I haven't used any of it, so I don't know how well they work. Also, I'm not affiliated with any of these lists or the devices/software on them.

> Point-N-Click is a free virtual mouse designed for people with disabilities that make it harder to use click a mouse. As long as the user can move a mouse, trackball or other pointing device, he can make the virtual mouse click.

https://patient-innovation.com/post/539

> Computer Accessibility Software

https://inclusiveinc.org/pages/computer-accessibility-software

> X-Mouse Button Control (XMBC) allows you to create application and window specific profiles. This in turn, allows you to re-configure your mouse behaviour for individual applications or windows. For each profile you can also configure up to 10 'layers' of different button configurations which you can switch between using hot-keys or mouse buttons.

https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

> This factsheet provides details of some of the alternative keyboard, mouse and other pointing devices available. It also gives information on adaptations you can make to standard keyboards and mice. There are so many choices and variations, we cannot cover every single piece of equipment in this factsheet.

https://abilitynet.org.uk/factsheets/keyboard-and-mouse-alternatives-and-adaptations

Answer (score 0):

In the USA the Trace center does much of this work, try contacting them https://trace.umd.edu/contact/. They should be able to point you at a local accessment center that will have the 101 different mouse replacements designed for disabled people to try out.